Unmock ESM module for one test using Jest
I'm mocking express-jwt in the setupAfterEnv.js file.
// setupAfterEnv.js
jest.unstable_mockModule("express-jwt", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("express-jwt"),
    expressjwt: () => (req, res, next) => {
        req.auth = {...};
        return next();
    },
}));

And I would like to have the non mocked version of the package for one test. I'm trying to test that an invalid or non existant token triggers my error handler (see last code sample). My test is close to the following
//myMiddleware.test.js
import request from "supertest";

test("my test", () => {
    await request(app).get("/") // app is my Express app
    expect(...)
})

My express app looks like
const app = express();
app.use(expressjwt({...}))
app.get("/", controllerMiddleware)
app.use(errorHandler) // I'm trying to test invalid tokens are catched here

I've tried using spyOn and importing the spy and setting a new implementation, I've tried jest.restoreAllMocks() and also calling jest.unstable_mockModule directly in my test but none of these solution worked.

Not sure if there's a good way to address this from the side of module mocking, but at least you can do: const moduleOriginal = jest.requireActual("express-jwt"); const expressjwtOriginal = moduleOriginal.expressjwt; expressjwtMiddlewareSpy = jest.fn((req, res, next) => ... )); return {...moduleOriginal , expressjwt: () => expressjwtMiddlewareSpy, expressjwtOriginal, expressjwtMiddlewareSpy }. This allows to keep a reference to the spy in tests and do expressjwtMiddlewareSpy.mockImplementationOnce(expressjwtOriginal())

@EstusFlask I tried importing the spy or adding it to the global object and using mockImplementationOnce. It didn't work I still had the first mock implementation

Did you try exactly the code from the previous comment? The tricky part is that you need the same expressjwtMiddlewareSpy  spy between expressjwt calls in order to be able to affect it
